# Why do I always get the last elements of my string array?

Tags: c, string, buffer

I am trying to read all strings from a text file and save them in an array of strings.
However, when I try to print the contents of my string array only the last part is printed. 
Why does my code only copy the last string?

#### My code

```
# include <stdio.h>
# define BUFFERSIZE 100

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
   char buffer[BUFFERSIZE];

   int i = 0;
   char *text[BUFFERSIZE];

   while(fgets(buffer, BUFFERSIZE, stdin) != NULL){
          text[i] = buffer;
          i++;
   }

   int j = 0;
   for (j=0; j<sizeof(text)/sizeof(char); i++){
          printf("%s\n", text[j]);
   }

   return 0;
}
```

#### My text file

```
ESD can create spectacular electric sparks (thunder and lightning is a large-scale ESD       event), but also less dramatic forms which may be neither seen nor heard, yet still be large enough to cause damage to sensitive electronic devices.
Electric sparks require a field strength above about 4 kV/cm in air, as notably occurs in lightning strikes. Other forms of ESD include corona discharge from sharp electrodes and brush discharge from blunt electrodes.
```

#### Output

```
>>> make 1_17; ./1_17 < example.txt
m blunt electrodes.

m blunt electrodes.

m blunt electrodes.

m blunt electrodes.

...
```

Comment: The assignment `test[i] = buffer` copies the location of buffer into the array over and over. look at `strdup` or `malloc + strcpy`

Comment: Look at the *address* stored in each `test[i]` slot, then consider what it means that they're all the *same* address. Hmmm...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are two issues.  The first is that for all you `i`s, `text[i]` contains the same buffer which you've used multiple times.  The second is that in your printing code, you're only printing `text[0]`.

#### Using the same buffer

There's only one buffer declared,

```
char buffer[BUFFERSIZE];
```

and while you modify its contents many times in the loop, it's always the same buffer (i.e., the same storage area in memory), so

```
text[i] = buffer;
```

makes every element of `text` contain the (address of) the same `buffer`.  You need to *copy* the contents of `buffer` into a new string and store that in `text[i]` instead.  You can duplicate the string using, e.g., [`strdup`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strdup) if you can use POSIX functions, as in

```
text[i] = strdup(buffer);
```

`strdup` uses `malloc` to allocate the space for the string, so if you're using this in a larger application, be sure to `free` those strings later.  In your simple application, though, they'll be freed when the application exits, so you're not in too much trouble.

If you can only use standard C functions, you'll probably want [`strcpy`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strcpy) which will make you do a little bit more work.  (You'll need to allocate a string big enough to hold the current contents of `buffer`, and then copy `buffer`'s contents into it.  You'll still want to `free` them afterwards.

#### Printing only `text[0]`

However, you've also got an issue with your printing code.  You're indexing into `text` with `j`, but never modifying `j` (you're incrementing `i` with `i++`), so you're always printing the same string (which is actually the *first* in the array, not the last, but its contents are the same as the lsat string that you read from the file):

```
 int j = 0;
 for (j=0; j<sizeof(text)/sizeof(char); i++){
        printf("%s\n", text[j]);
 }
```

After the first loop, `i` is the number of strings that you've got, so you probably just want:

```
int j;
for ( j=0; j < i; j++ ) {
  printf("%s\n", text[j]);
}
```

Comment: Note that `strdup` is not C standard, but POSIX standard.

Comment: @Kninnug oh, good catch;  I'll add a link to strcpy, too.

Comment: Also `sizeof(text)/sizeof(char)` is not what the OP really wants. It should be  `sizeof(text)/sizeof(text[0])`. Using only `sizeof(text)` is also wrong , as it's `BUFFERSIZE * sizeof (char*)`.

Comment: or better yet, why not just `for ( j=0; j < i; j++ ) { ...text[j]... }`, since `i` (from the previous loop) is the number of strings that were read.

Answer (score 3):

Also, in addition to the answers already posted, you're incrementing `i` in your for loop, not `j`.

Answer (score 1):

Look at this loop:

```
while(fgets(buffer, BUFFERSIZE, stdin) != NULL){
    text[i] = buffer;
    i++;
}
```

You're setting every element of your array to the exact same value: the value of `buffer`, which is a pointer to a piece of memory. On every iteration you're reading data over the top of where you read it last time.

To fix this, you'd need to allocate a *new* buffer on each iteration, and set the array value to a pointer to that new buffer. That way each element of the array will point to a different section of memory.